# Facebook and Proguard error

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, gradle, proguard

I am using Android Studio with proguard. My app uses Facebook and I am not able to build with these settings on in my gradle file:

```
minifyEnabled true

shrinkResources true
```

I get multiple errors:

```
Error:(59, 29) error: cannot find symbol class StatusCallback

Error:(169, 76) error: cannot find symbol class GraphUserCallback

Error:(65, 41) error: cannot find symbol class NewPermissionsRequest

Error:(162, 76) error: cannot find symbol class GraphUserCallback

Error:(681, 41) error: cannot find symbol class NewPermissionsRequest
```

com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback, com.facebook.Request.GraphUserCallback is Interfaces and com.facebook.Session.NewPermissionsRequest is a public static final class

I have added

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

and

```
-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}
```

To my proguard file but it does not help. StatusCallback is defined in one of my fragments like this:

```
public com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback mFacebookCallback = new com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(com.facebook.Session session, com.facebook.SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (mFacebookFetchEmail || mLoginWithFacebookClicked) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }

    }
};
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does not look like a ProGuard error, but missing imports. Are you sure it builds OK with `minifyEnabled false`?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work with these proguard rules:

```
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn com.facebook.android.BuildConfig
-keepattribute InnerClasses

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepattributes *Annotation*

#modify for Facebook
-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}
-keep public class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
-keepclassmembers class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback {
   public *;
}
-keep public class * implements com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback


-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses


-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

Comment: It's probably the InnerClasses line that fixed it since all of those are inner classes.